# Can we find $x$ such that $\det[x^2 A + x B + C] = 0$?

Tags: matrices, determinant

If $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}, \mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{C}^{4 \times 4}$ are invertible matrices, is there a way to find $x$ such that the following determinant vanishes?

$$\det \left( x^2 \mathbf{A} + x \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{C}\right) = 0$$

Comment: You should specify the underlying field (e.g. $\mathbb R, \mathbb C$ or something else altogether).  If, say, you are talking about $\mathbb R$ then taking $A=B=C$ all to be the identity matrix gives a counterexample, though that counterexample doesn't extend to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391)

Comment: @lulu, thanks, I have updated the question. The matrices $A,B,C,D$  are of dim. 4 and have complex entries (Apologies for my physics language).

Comment: For such an $x$, the vanishing of this determinant means that there exists a vector $v$ such that. $x^2 (Av)+x(Bv)+(Cv)=0$. So this falls under the rubric of a generalized eigenvalue problem, which may be useful for Googling. Along related lines, a matrix-valued function which is polynomial w/r/t some scalar is known as a [matrix pencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_pencil). So you're essentially interested in singular matrix pencils over 4-by-4 matrices. For an entire paper on this, see: https://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/466/1/38198.pdf.

Comment: And $x$ is also from complex numbers? The determinant is a polynomial in $x$, so then it has a complex root.

Comment: This can help you probably. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Quadratic_eigenvalue_problem

Comment: Another useful link: https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~bai/Winter09/qep_slides.pdf

Answer (score -4):

If we allow complex $x$ then yes. If not then in 1-dimensional case it is not that difficult to find numbers $A,B,C$ such that $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ has no real roots.
For complex numbers - determinant can be expressed as a sum of products of entries over permutations. So, for some numbers $M,N,K$  the question is if $Mx^2 + Nx + K$ has a root. Which is of course true.
Though there could be a degenerate case when $M$ and $N$ are zero and $C$ is not. This happens in 1 dimensional case when $A=0, B=0$, and $C=1$. In words the full answer is if $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ is not a constant matrix then yes. Otherwise, only if $C=0$.

Comment: Added explanation for complex numbers @Dietrich Burde

Comment: You could just write that $\det(x^2A+xB+C)$ is a non-constant polynomial in $x$, which has a complex root.

Comment: If the matrices are $n\times n$ then the determinant will generally be a degree $2n$ polynomial in $x$.